# Why use parse offline local database in android when there is sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform, android-sqlite

I have searched but did't find any satisfactory answer. I have a confusion that why `parse.com` has announced `offline local database` when there is sqlite. 
Is there is any advantage in using it?

Answer (score 0):

One major advantage is how ParseObjects are so simple to use where SQLite requires knowledge of SQL queries. Parse local data store is just a simpler way for local databases. It is the same concept for Parse itself. Why use their service when you can run MySQL on your own server. The answer for both is to make it simple, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Data can be saved locally(when no internet to sync with online database) for further sync when connection available.